# Compiz place windows not working at login

Tags: compiz, multiple-monitors, ccsm

I'm trying to set up a dual kiosk with Firefox and chrome in kiosk mode.
Running Ubuntu 12.10 on an Intel NUC i3 with dual HDMI out on HD4000 grahics.
I have two 1080p displays on the HDMI outputs, works perfect.

In CCSM, I have set up two rules, one for Chrome to be placed at 0,0.
One other rule for Firefox to be placed at 1920, 0.

Both rules work perfect, when I start Chrome it's displayed on the first display.
When I start Firefox it's displayed on my second display.

So, I set chrome and Firefox in the 'startup applications', even with a X-GNOME-startup-delay=10 so the network gets initializes meanwhile.

The user is set to autologin, when firing up the system everything works, chrome start at 0,0 (display 1) but Firefox should be placed at 1920,0 (second display).
This doesn't happen, Firefox is opened on top of Chrome.

When I close Firefox and then launch it again, CCSM gets it and places it on 1920,0 (second display).

Problem: why it Firefox placed right when I launch is, but not when it is automatically launched at startup / login?
Also tried to to add `compiz --replace` to the start-up applications, no result.

Anybody that can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add a startup delay to 'compiz --replace' and see if that solves your problem.
You may need to write a simple bash script and add *that* to startup if the following doesn't work for you.

[image]

Comment: Just tried your solution, but doesn't do the trick. I already added a delay to the startup of Chrome and Firefox so that compiz has time to startup.

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed! Just found out that i didn't type Delay with a capital D in X-GNOME-startup-delay.

So the delay wasn't working at all. Now the browsers boot with a delay of 2 second so compiz has time to start running.